# Compactly supported Lipschitz function

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ an open set, $f: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ Lipschitz continuous (with constant $L$) and with compact support. Let $f'$ defined as $f'(x)=0$ if $x \notin \Omega$, $f'(x)$ otherwise. Is $f'$ Lipschitz continuous?

Intuitively yes, as one could take as the Lipschitz costant of $f'$ to be $\max\{1,L\}\sup f$.

Comment: What does 'extending to $0$' mean?

Comment: If you extend $f:[-1, 1] \to \Bbb R$, $f(x)= x$ by setting $f(x) = 0$ for  $|x| >1$ then the extended function  is not even continuous. Perhaps you want to clarify the question?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Edited

Comment: The question is still not stated properly.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Edited

Comment: Your question has been clearly answered by Martin R in his comment.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy what about $S$ being open?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extended function is Lipschitz but the constant need not be $\max \{1,L\}$.

There  is  a positive distance $r$ from the support of $f$ to the complement of $S$. If $|x-y| <r$ then either $x$ and $y$ both belong to $S$ (in which case $|f(x)-f(y) \leq L |x-y|$) or they both lie outside the support (in which case $|f(x)-f(y) \leq 0 |x-y|$). However when we  consider points with $|x-y| \geq r$ one of the points may be in the support and the other outside $S$. Here we use the fact that $f$ is bounded. Let $|f| \leq M$. Then $|f(x)-f(y)| \leq \frac {2M} r  |x-y|$. So f is Lipschitz.